# how to pass edited cell value to backend in ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am  trying to send the edited data in cell (ag-grid angular) to server, but i donot know how to do this, can anyone share me code examples
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkRo2.png)

```
 onAddRow()
  {
    this.agGrid.api.updateRowData({
 add: [
{"DeviceMacAddress": rowNode.setDataValue(col,value)}
]
    });
```

in html

```
<button (click) = "onAddRow()">ADD ROW </butoton>
```

i do not know where i have to set the edited data and need to pass the edityed data along with first row data

first data in rows are coming from server and second row is added manually by using Add Row button ,here I am adding mac address and i want to push this to rowdata
this is my problem i am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add this piece of code in the ag grid property:

```
      onCellValueChanged: (event) => this.inlineEdit(event),
```

Step 2:

```
inlineEdit(event){

        //you api call to send data to the server.

}
```

I hope it is what you are looking for :)